# Recursive sorting algorithm

Tags: python, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

I wrote a recursive sorting algorithm and was wondering what would be the run time complexity of this. The bulk of the work is done in the `push_up` function, which I think is linear in time. There are a linear amount of recursive calls though. If \$n\$ is the length of the list, would the runtime then be \$O(n^2)\$?

```
def sort(lst):
    """Recursive sorting algorithm. Sorts the remainder of the list 
    and then pushes the first element up to its appropriate position"""

   if lst == []:
       return []
   if len(lst) == 1:
       return [lst[0]]
   elt = lst[0]
   sorted_lst = sort(lst[1:])
   return push_up(elt, sorted_lst)

def insert(val, lst, i):
    """Inserts [val] into [lst] at index [i] """

    return lst[:i] + [val] + lst[i:]

def push_up(val, lst):
    """Pushes [val] up the list until it reaches its sorted position.
    Precondition: lst is sorted"""
    start = 0
    while start < len(lst) and lst[start] < val:
        start += 1

    return insert(val, lst, start)
```

Comment: If I am not wrong that is insertion sort, which runs at $O(n^2)$ in worst case scenario.

Comment: @XCoderX you need to backslash the dollar signs here to get mathjax. e.g. \$O(n^2)\$ is written \\$O(n^2)\\$

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

You can see that your `sort` function operates by recursing directly on itself, using a shorter-by-one version of its list parameter. This is stopped when the list is of length 0 or 1. (That code should be cleaned up.) So your `sort` recurses `n-1` times, given `n >= 2`.

Each time it recurses, `sort` calls `push_up` once. The `push_up` function linearly scans the list, which is of length 1, then 2, then `... n-1`.

So in the worst case (input array is reverse-sorted) you have scans of total length \$ \sum 1 ... (n-1) \$, which makes your code \$ O(n^2) \$.

Answer (score 4):

I have a few suggestions for improving your code.

- Good job using docstrings. Perhaps you should mention what the parameters actually represent, e.g. `lst` represents the list to be sorted.
- > ```
  > if lst == []:
  >     return []
  > if len(lst) == 1:
  >     return [lst[0]]
  > ```

  This could be replaced by:

  ```
  if len(lst) <= 1:
      return lst[:]
  ```

  The `[:]` is slice notation for a copy of the entire list.
- > ```
  > def insert(val, lst, i):
  >     """Inserts [val] into [lst] at index [i] """
  >
  >     return lst[:i] + [val] + lst[i:]
  > ```

  Since `lst` is already guaranteed to be a copy here, no need to make four new lists. Just insert the item into the existing `lst` and return it, e.g.

  ```
  lst.insert(i, val)
  return lst
  ```
- > ```
  > def push_up(val, lst):
  >     """Pushes [val] up the list until it reaches its sorted position.
  >     Precondition: lst is sorted"""
  >     start = 0
  >     while start < len(lst) and lst[start] < val:
  >         start += 1
  > ```

  It is not Pythonic to increment your own index to iterate over a list. Instead you should use the builtin `enumerate`:

  ```
  for (pos, item) in enumerate(lst):
      if item >= val:
          return insert(val, lst, pos)
  # if not found
  lst.append(item)
  return lst
  ```

Comment: The parentheses around `pos` and `item` are superfluous (though arguably better for readability).